# extract information from string using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have data like this i want to extract some information from x and y

```
x= "{\"device_codename\": \"nikel\", \"brand\": \"Xiaomi\"}" 
y= {"percent_incoming_nighttime": 0.88, "percent_outgoing_daytime": 9.29}
```

The result

```
device_codename   brand     percent_incoming_nighttime percent_outgoing_daytime
nikel             Xiaomi    0.88                       9.29
```

I have tired using grep but iam getting errors any suggestion?

```
grep("device_codename", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly JSON format. There are tools to handle those.

```
library(jsonlite)

x = "{\"device_codename\": \"nikel\", \"brand\": \"Xiaomi\"}" 
y = '{"percent_incoming_nighttime": 0.88, "percent_outgoing_daytime": 9.29}'

> unlist(fromJSON(x))
device_codename           brand 
        "nikel"        "Xiaomi" 
> unlist(fromJSON(y))
percent_incoming_nighttime   percent_outgoing_daytime 
                      0.88                       9.29
```

Comment: That is really nice. But when i run in many rows i got this error Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(encoding)) return(0L) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(i)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0):

After removing the braces (`{}`) and double quotes with `gsub`, read the substring after the `:` using `read.csv` into a `data.frame` and then change the column names with the substring i.e. before the `:`

```
v1 <- gsub('"|[{}]', "", c(x, y))
out <- read.csv(text=paste(gsub("\\w+:\\s+", "", v1), collapse=", "),
       header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(out) <- unlist(regmatches(v1, gregexpr("\\w+(?=:)", v1, perl = TRUE)))


out
#  device_codename   brand percent_incoming_nighttime percent_outgoing_daytime
#1           nikel  Xiaomi                       0.88                     9.29
```

NOTE: No external packages used

---

Or using `RJSONIO` and `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RJSONIO)
list(x, y) %>%
    map(~ fromJSON(.x) %>% 
            as.list %>%
            as_tibble) %>%
       bind_cols
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  device_codename brand  percent_incoming_nighttime percent_outgoing_daytime
#  <chr>           <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
#1 nikel           Xiaomi                       0.88                     9.29
```

#### data

```
x <- "{\"device_codename\": \"nikel\", \"brand\": \"Xiaomi\"}"
y <- "{\"percent_incoming_nighttime\": 0.88, \"percent_outgoing_daytime\": 9.29}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i try to run the last line. colnames(out) it says expected ',' after expression. could you check that please.

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle  Sorry, a missing bracket at the end.  Fixed it

Comment: There is still an error bcoz the number of open brackets are 3. So, i added another one at the end. But when i run it, there is no output ?

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle  Now, it is working fine for me.  Can you check once more with the same example in my post

Comment: That is nice, but when i run it on the whole dataframe i got this error: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(encoding)) return(0L) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(i)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (is.na(encoding)) return(0L) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (is.na(i)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @HaniIhlayyle  Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem with your example

Answer (score 0):

completed jsonlite solution (Roman Luštrik)

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

xx_x= "{\"device_codename\": \"nikel\", \"brand\": \"Xiaomi\"}" 
xx_y= "{\"percent_incoming_nighttime\": 0.88, \"percent_outgoing_daytime\": 9.29}"

c(jsonlite::fromJSON(xx_x), jsonlite::fromJSON(xx_y)) %>% 
  reshape2::melt() %>% mutate(myrow = 1) %>% 
  spread(L1, value)
```

result

```
  myrow  brand device_codename percent_incoming_nighttime percent_outgoing_daytime
1     1 Xiaomi           nikel                       0.88                     9.29
```